# Cannot get Django App to serve correct URL

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I am trying to follow the django tutorial to setup a simple Django App and Django Project that serves two URLs: "/" (index) and "/testweb" .

If I navigate to `http://localhost:8000/testweb`, I see "index!" and not "testweb!" . What am I doing wrong?

My project is called `testweb` and my app is called `foo`. Here's `testweb/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('foo.urls')),
    url(r'^testweb/', include('foo.urls')),
)
```

And here's `foo/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.http import HttpResponse
from foo import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', (lambda x: HttpResponse("index!"))),
    url(r'^testweb/', (lambda x: HttpResponse("testweb!"))),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> As I said, django is running index() for both URLs.

Given your code, when you go to `/testweb`, Django matches the second line from `testweb/urls.py` and then the first line in `foo/urls.py`. Try `/testweb/testweb`. You'll see that this runs `(lambda x: HttpResponse("testweb!"))`.

That's happening because you're pointing both URLs to `include('foo.urls')`. Going to `/testweb/` matches the second URL in `testweb/urls.py`, and which `include`s `foo.urls` and looks for a match there. Since you've got nothing in your URL after `/testweb/`, the resolver then hits the first URL in `foo.urls`, which is for the `index` lambda. `include` a different URLConf or just reference the views directly, like:

```
# testweb/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', (lambda x: HttpResponse("index!")), name='index'),
    url(r'^testweb/', (lambda x: HttpResponse("testweb!")), name='testweb'),
)
```

and you'll get your expected results.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some way to more loosely couple the project and app? I had hoped that I could just configure the project so that it just passes certain URLs to the app, and then relies on the app to sort it out.

Comment: Yeah, that's what `include` is for. The problem with your code is that it's including the same exact behavior for URLs rooted at `/` and `/testweb`. Change the root URLConf (`testweb/urls.py`) to point to different includes for the different URLs.

Comment: When you go to `/testweb`, Django matches the second line from `testweb/urls.py`, and then the first line in `foo/urls.py`.

Comment: So is the best way to do this to have two `urls.py` files for the app?, e.g. `url(r'^$', include('foo_index.urls')), url(r'^testweb/', include('foo_testweb.urls')` ?

Comment: The best way is to have your app's `urls.py` specify the views you want hit.

Comment: Try restating your question in terms of expected behavior and why you expect that behavior given your code.

Comment: Right, but there are two `url.py` files. As I understand it the "project" `url.py` file should match the URLs that are specific to the _foo_ app and then pass those requests to foo. So logically, what I was aiming for was something that said "pass requests for '/' and '/testweb' to the app named _foo_," and then the url.py file for _foo_ would figure out which views to invoke. Thanks for all your help on this!

Comment: The project `url.py` is the the one that's specified in `settings.py` and is the URLConf is that first consulted when a request comes in. It can specify a namespace, such as `testweb` and then specify that all URLs in that namespace—all URLs starting with `testweb`—should look into another URLConf. So, if you include `foo.urls` for the `testweb` namespace, requests to `testweb/testweb` will look for a `^testweb` entry int he `foo.urls` URLConf.